# Schroedinger equation in Differential geometric language

Tags: quantum-mechanics, differential-geometry, schroedinger-equation

I have reading about manifolds and tangents spaces and lie derivatives.

I have been wondering is there is a way to write Schrödinger equation in this formalism?

Comment: The Schrodinger equation is nonrelativistic, so if you're talking about doing the Schrodinger equation in a curved spacetime, I don't think that works.

Comment: You can study Schrödinger operators on manifolds, yes, but for the examples that you find in most common applications, this is overkill. One case where this arises naturally concerns many-body Schrödinger operators after the Born-Oppenheimer approximation, which e. g. describe chemical reactions. Here, the Berry connection arises naturally as a connection and the space is that of most likely reaction paths. This is definitely not entry-level material.

Comment: You briefly mention advanced mathematical concepts, but the physical context is missing. I have to trust others that this question is about the Schrödinger equation in curved space. Can you clarify?

Comment: Note that the Schrödinger equation does not contain rest mass, so you will first have to add that.

Comment: Note that the Schrödinger equation is not even Galileo covariant.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest curved space (i.e. curved Riemannian manifold) generalization of the Euclidean space forumulation of Schrödinger's equation can be found on page 47 of Geroch's notes on geometric quantum mechanics at the Univ. of Chicago from 1974 which were published in paperback form in 2013 [here](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B01FIXSRLW).

This is (for a classical Hamiltonian at most quadratic in momenta, as not to conflict the famous [Groenewold-van Hove no-go theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Canonical_quantization#Groenewold's_theorem))

$$\frac{d}{dt}\psi(x,t) = \frac{1}{i\hbar} \left[\left(\frac{\hbar}{i}\right)^2 g^{ab} \nabla_a \nabla_b \psi(x,t) +\left(\frac{\hbar}{i}\right)\left(A^a (x) \nabla_a \psi (x,t) + \frac{1}{2}\psi (x,t) \nabla_a A^a (x)\right) + V(x,t) \psi (x,t)\right] $$, where $H_{class} = g^{ab} p_a p_b + A^a p_a + V(x)$ and $\nabla_a$ is typically the covariant derivative associated to the Levi-Civita connection.

A true differential-geometric forumulation of QM is clear in [Ashtekar&Schilling's](https://arxiv.org/abs/gr-qc/9706069v1) review. This is a true text written by a GRist, with all full machinery of differential geometry.